How can contantenated codes help qubits be robust to ionizing radiation?
In Quantum error correction below the surface code threshold, it was discovered that correlated errors set a noise floor of $10^{-10}$ for Willow. In Beyond NISQ: The Megaquop Machine, Preskill's suggestions for reducing this noise floor are to place the computer underground or to use concatenated codes.
What properties do concatenated codes have that would potentially make them immune to these types of correlated errors? Why doesn't the Surface code have those properties?

A concatenated code can have its underlying surface code patches be far apart, so a cosmic ray hit can only destroy one of its pieces at a time. Whereas one surface code patch must have internals that are local, to measure the stabilizers fast.
Personally I think hardware mitigations have worked amazingly to suppress this problem already, so that's more likely to be the solution. But concatenation will still be used, because it improves density.

How do you concatenate a surface code (SC) patch with another? Every reference I've been able to find concatenates SC with another code like GKP+SC or Hamming code + SC. Doesn't 2 SC patches far apart mean that 2 logical qubits (LQ) are created, not one? How would this work on the Willow experiment, where only 1 LQ was created?

@VictoryOmole See https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.04522 . It doesn't spread the patches out like you would if you were trying to avoid correlated destruction from cosmic rays, but otherwise shows how it's done.

To add to Craig's answer, Concatenate codes, save qubits: Modularity in comparison with the quantum low-
density parity-check (LDPC) code says code concatenation can be made modular by having each code be it's own module and interconnecting the modules with others when concatenating. Cosmic rays hitting one module will not destroy the entire logical memory if the modules are sufficiently far apart.
